# putting a '&' after the type

Tags: c++, types, parameters, declaration, ampersand

I am fairly new to programming. I am just moving on to C++ from C in my college courses, and I encountered something that I haven't seen before in C. Sometimes after the type, either in a function declaration or passing a parameter, a `&` immediately follows the type. For example, we use a struct called Customer in one of our projects, and some of the functions pass `Customer&`. Why is the ampersand after the type, as opposed to in front? Thanks!

Comment: It's a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) - now you know that, you can google appropriately to learn more about how it differs from a pointer ;-o

Comment: ah, it makes sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

References in C++ simply allow for a cleaner way to execute the following code:

```
int x = 16;
int* y = &x;
cout << *y;
```

Which could be written instead as

```
int x = 16;
int& y = x;
cout << y;
```

When defining functions, a reference allows a function to change the value of parameters without causing the user of the function to put an ampersand before everything. E.g.

```
void func( int& a )
{
    a = 5;
}

void main()
{
    int A = 10;
    func( A );
    cout << A; // Will output '5'
}
```

Be careful with this type of mutation, as a programmer using functions like this without checking the implementation might not realize that the function is changing the value of the parameters unless the intent is obvious. `init_server(my_server)` would be an example of a case where it's obvious, but `to_json(my_struct)` would clearly be an example where you should not be using a reference to change the struct in any way.

But, one of the most important uses of references, would be function like

```
int sum_vector( const vector<int>& a ) {
   int sum = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
      sum += a[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

If you tried to make sum_vector take in a vector, and you passed in a vector with 100 million entries, then it would have to copy them all over, taking forever. You could take in a pointer, but then the internal parts of the function would have to constantly dereference, and it must called with `sum_vector(&myvec)`, which is more annoying than `sum_vector(myvec)`. In this way, using a const reference, you can prevent the highly inefficient copying of the whole vector into the function body, while keeping syntax neat. Using const lets you reassure yourself that you're not going to change the vector that you were given. And, it also assures the user of your function that you won't change it. Similarly, `void to_json(const some_struct&)` would be a better function definition as it ensures you won't change the user's data.